# How to prevent automatic jumping to the next track?

Tags: vlc-media-player, windows-media-player, playlists, daum-pot-player

I need to play a list of mp3 files one by one. I mean I need to go to the next track manually. I tried to do so in PotPlayer, WMP and VLC. All of them jump to the next track after playing the current file. How to prevent this?

Comment: MPC-HC player provides this feature.

Comment: Did you look through *all* the relevant options in VLC? I'm pretty certain you can turn this off.

Comment: I have the same problem. I checked all the advanced settings in VLC but nothing explains how to turn it off. This is annoying

Comment: @pablorenato use MPC-HC player

Answer (score 11, accepted):

VLC does it like a champ, under tools > preferences, first set it to show all in the bottom right, then select the playlist item from the list on the left, and you can see a whole bunch of playback options and good help for each one if you ouse over!

VLC is always champ.

Comment: On VLC 3.0.6 Vetinari on Windows, it was Tools> Preferences>> (lower-*left*) Show settings: All>> left menu: Playlist>> Play and pause.

Comment: I've gotta give the points to @Krubo for this... 
The actual answer doesn't tell you the right toggle: PLAY AND PAUSE.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old, outdated response but I was looking for this same feature (specifically to stop after each *audio* track, not videos) and this page @David Gold helped me get to the right setting. I only needed the setting related to audio files:

1. Click on Tools/Preferences
2. Look for "Show settings" in the very bottom left of the preferences screen and change it to "All"
3. In the left column, scroll down to "Playlist" in the left column and click it.
4. Look for "Play and stop" and select the checkbox, then click on "Save" at the bottom right to keep the changes.

This setting will stop playback at the end of a played track without advancing to the next track automatically.

You'll need to remove this checkbox later if you want to play a playlist and have it advance the normal way track-to-track.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

How about opening each file through a file manager?

Thats what I do whenever I'm looking through the windows sound files when changing the windows sound scheme. Same goes for looking for a new ring tone on my mobile.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

With VLC you can stop the automatic skipping by selecting the "no loop" icon at the bottom of the viewport. The icon will show a vertical bar in the center when the no-loop option is selected.

Answer (score 0):

In WMP, create a new playlist containing the MP3 files that you want to play this way. Then, instead of double-clicking each file in the playlist, right-click each file and select `Play` (*not* `Play all`).

`Play all`, which is the default action, starts playing the selected file, while putting the current list of songs in the `Play` tab. The `Play` action, on the other hand, only puts the selected file in the `Play` tab.

Answer (score 0):

Do this to play individuals files in a VLC playlist one at a time

Click Tools - Click Preferences  -  (on interface tab ) scroll down to 'playlist and Instances' , check mark the 'Pause on last frame of video' - click save

Answer (score 0):

As a more generalized supplement to the existing answers (since OP does tag multiple media players), the option you're referring to is typically identified using the vernacular term "repeat one" or "loop one".  This option will repeat the same track indefinitely until you choose to advance to the next or open another file for playback.

Note that on some media players, there exists separate and distinct configuration options for looping in for normal playback as opposed to looping when playing from a playlist (this can become confusing when you perform a search on the available setting values or for hotkey binding options).  In terms of accessing from the frontend UI, you may need to first open the playlist window and then use the repeat function shown within that frame.